# What is a field group theory and how is it different from a ring

Tags: group-theory

I was wondering what a field is defined to be in group theory, and how it is different from a ring. ( see the title)

Comment: A field is a particular type of ring: one where every non-zero element has an inverse. Can you clarify what you mean by "what a field is defined to be in group theory"?

Comment: Ideally, you would include any research you have done to answer your own question. In particular, you would include the definitions are that you are using in your course, textbook, and explain how you can't find a difference between them.

Answer (score 2):

A field is a particular kind of ring: it has to be commutative, and every element, except the additive identity, must have a multiplicative inverse (in particular, every field has a multiplicative identity; some texts don't require rings to have multiplicative identities). Also, the additive identity and multiplicative identity must be different, so the trivial ring is not a field. (And the ["field with one element,"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Field_with_one_element) isn't.)

(Also, I'm not sure what you mean by ". . . in group theory." Fields and rings aren't defined differently in group theory than in the rest of mathematics, modulo the confusion mentioned above re: multiplicative identities, which has nothing to do with the context being group theory or not.)